# Test SSL Certificate for MQ SSL Testing

Tags: c#, ssl, ibm-mq

I am in the process of testing MQ calls over the SSL. I woul like to know where i can get some demo SSL certificates. That i can use them for testing.

I also would like to know if there any code sample which i can use to pass SSL kind of connection. The exaple i am looking is in C#

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self-signed certificate to test MQ connectivity.  As far as example code goes, you can refer to the IBM docs.  Both of the documents below have sections containing example code for connecting to a queue manager using ssl.

[XMS Message Service API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24011756)  (I don't believe that this is supported in MQ7 yet, but I may be wrong about that.)

[WebsphereMQ Classes for .NET](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqzav.doc/csq8709.htm)

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/httpservers/doc/v1312/ibm/9atikeyu.htm#HDRKMU3G

I have read about self service keys but, i would like to know how i need to put the server and client stuff in this case. Can u please send me if u have any links related to that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.  If you are asking how to setup SSL channels on a queue manager then I would use the ssl wizard. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24010367